# Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.content.SharedPreferences$Editor.putString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I am trying to save preferences so when user types in name and clicks save, it releases an alert dialog and if they say yes, it takes them to a welcome page. however, if they go back to the first page, they do not need to type name in again, it'll just say (WELCOME, USER). however its giving me an error, a null exception error.Please help!
Also, I would need for the app to save the username, so when the user clicks the back button, and then goes to the first page to try and type in their names again, it just pushes them to the welcome page, since the name has been types before
I will just add snippets of my code relevant to the question.

this is the page where the user types in name;

```
  import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    public class userPreferences extends Activity {
    EditText editText;
    Button save;
    public static final String NAME="UserName";
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    String n;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.userpreferences);
        editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences(NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(userPreferences.this);

          @Override
          public void onClick(View arg0) {

                      alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Dialog");
              alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to save?");
              alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                          @Override
                          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                              n=editText.getText().toString();
                              sharedPreferences=getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                              editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
                              editor.putString(NAME,n);
                              editor.apply();
                              startActivity(new Intent(userPreferences.this,Welcome.class));

                          }
                      });
                      alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", null);
                      alertDialog.show();


          }
      });

    }


}
```

this is the welcome page;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Welcome extends Activity {

TextView textView;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
public static final String NAME="UserName";
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
String n;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.welcome);
    textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText("Welcome," + editor.putString(NAME, n));
    sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences(NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor.apply();

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    startActivity(new Intent(Welcome.this, MainActivity.class));
    return;


}
```

the error in the logical reads

```
Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.content.SharedPreferences$Editor android.content.SharedPreferences$Editor.putString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change from

```
sharedPreferences=getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to

```
sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences(NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
if(!sharedPreferences.getString(NAME,"Default value").equals("Default value")){
  startActivity(new Intent(userPreferences.this, Welcome.class));
  finish();
}
```

Also in your welcome class

```
sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences(NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText("Welcome," + sharedPreferences.getString(NAME,"Default value"));
editor = = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString(NAME, sharedPreferences.getString(NAME,"Default value"));
editor.apply();
```

Comment: it runs but it does not save the username

Comment: it still does not save it. I have an onBackPressed method, which makes the back button skip the login page and go directly to the first page, but when i get to the first page, and click the button to the login page, it just brings up a new login page, instead of the welcome page

Comment: no i want the app to remember the name already and just send the user to the welcome page

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
// open your preferences using the name you originally used to create it
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);

// open for editing
editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

// you probably don't want to use the same name here as preferences name 
editor.putString(NAME,n);
editor.apply();
```

Additionally you are trying to use editor.putString(NAME, n); this does not read from preferences do:

```
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
String name = sharedPreferences.getString(NAME);

textView.setText("Welcome," + name);
```

**UPDATE** 
in order to save this user name for next time you must call the editor and save it after reading it again calling your calling editor.apply() on a null object. Here is a full working sample of your `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.welcome);
     textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

     sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
     String name = sharedPreferences.getString(NAME);

     textView.setText("Welcome," + name);
     editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
     editor.putString(NAME, name);
     editor.apply();

}
```

Comment: its not null, the app crashes before it gets to the welcome page and it seems to be the line                                                 textView.setText("Welcome," + editor.putString(NAME, n));                     causing it to crash, but i do not know why

Comment: @AriaMontgomery see updated answer you can't use editor to read name

Comment: the code works, but it does not save the username for next time

Comment: @AriaMontgomery you must save the name your reading again. try the above under update

Comment: it still does not save it. I have an onBackPressed method, which makes the back button skip the login page and go directly to the first page, but when i get to the first page, and click the button to the login page, it just brings up a new login page, instead of the welcome page

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that first, you are not initializing the `editor` object in the Welcome class and it is therefore null.

But, even if you initialize that, you will not get the desired behavior, because the editor is used to edit the SharedPreferences and cannot be used to retrieve the preference. `editor.putString(NAME, n)` stores a string and returns a boolean, it does not get the user's name. It is also null because you have not initialized it.

You don't even need the `Editor` object in the Welcome class, instead you need to use the `sharedPreferences` variable as follows:

```
TextView textView;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
public static final String NAME = "UserName";
public static final String defaultName = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.welcome);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    textView.setText("Welcome," + sharedPreferences.getString(NAME, defaultName));
}
```

EDIT: If you would like to skip the login activity if the user has already entered a username, then you would check if they have and then launch the activity directly from your login activity.

```
EditText editText;
Button save;
public static final String NAME="UserName";
public static final String default = "";
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
String n;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.userpreferences);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences(NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (sharedPreferences.getString(NAME, default).length() > 0) {
        // The user has already entered a username, so start the Welcome activity
        startActivity(new Intent(userPreferences.this, Welcome.class));
        finish();
    }
    // put the rest of your onCreate code here
}
```

Comment: the code works perfect! however, how do i make it remember the username once it has been entered?

Comment: @AriaMontgomery I looked at your `userPreferences` Activity and the code in there looks like it should work. See if you can change it in the `userPreferences` Activity and let me know if you see the change.

Comment: it still does not save it. maybe i should have added that I have an onBackPressed method, which makes the back button skip the login page and go directly to the first page, but when i get to the first page, and click the button to the login page, it just brings up a new login page, instead of the welcome page

Comment: @AriaMontgomery Ohhhh, I see, you want the login activity to get skipped if the user has entered a username... let me make a change to your login activity.

Comment: @AriaMontgomery I've updated the login activity to just open the welcome screen if the user has entered a username. Let me know if it works for you, and don't forget to add in your `AlertDialog` code after the if block so that the login dialog will show if they haven't logged in yet.